# iOS 7.1 update crash when switching between uitextfields with reason setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSShadow)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

We have a failry complex mobile application that uses a static table view for input.  With the update to ios 7.1 we are now getting a crash after a user goes through a few text fields without entering information, then enters something and moves to the next text field.  The crash is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSShadow)'
```

with this stack trace:

```
    * First throw call stack: (
0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010342b495 exceptionPreprocess + 165
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010318a99e objc_exception_throw + 43
2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001034aa544 -[NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 916
3 UIKit 0x0000000101eb877c -[UILabel setShadow:] + 339
4 UIKit 0x0000000101eb88b5 -[UILabel setShadowColor:] + 100
5 CoreFoundation 0x0000000103420f1c invoking + 140
6 CoreFoundation 0x00000001034b0e84 -[NSInvocation invokeUsingIMP:] + 212
7 UIKit 0x00000001021f0b4d workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget_block_invoke + 88
8 UIKit 0x0000000101d7eecb +[UIView _performCustomizableAppearanceModifications:] + 33
9 UIKit 0x00000001021f0ae3 workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget + 938
10 UIKit 0x00000001021ebfc9 +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:] + 3482
11 UIKit 0x0000000101d938fa 88-[UIView(Internal) performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]block_invoke + 63
12 UIKit 0x0000000101d93885 -[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 230
13 UIKit 0x0000000101d92e2c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1369
14 UIKit 0x0000000101d8b996 45-[UIView(Hierarchy) postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 128
15 UIKit 0x0000000101d8b85c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 276
16 UIKit 0x0000000101d952ac -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1508
17 UIKit 0x000000010237d922 -[UITextField willDetachFieldEditor:] + 96
18 UIKit 0x0000000101e1b48e -[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:] + 236
19 UIKit 0x0000000102375497 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 197
20 UIKit 0x0000000101e6b212 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 128
21 UIKit 0x00000001023752db -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 114
22 UIKit 0x0000000101e6b011 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 297
23 UIKit 0x0000000101d8b673 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 99
24 UIKit 0x0000000102374b08 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
25 UIKit 0x0000000102067d01 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 187
26 UIKit 0x0000000102069b30 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 1768
27 UIKit 0x000000010205ffc2 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 188
28 UIKit 0x000000010205ef28 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 357
29 UIKit 0x00000001020632d9 UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 53
30 UIKit 0x0000000102063261 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 257
31 UIKit 0x000000010205b337 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 93
32 UIKit 0x0000000101d6fa15 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928
33 UIKit 0x0000000101d706d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 909
34 UIKit 0x0000000101d4829a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
35 UIKit 0x0000000101d35aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
36 CoreFoundation 0x00000001033bad21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
37 CoreFoundation 0x00000001033ba5f2 CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
38 CoreFoundation 0x00000001033d646f CFRunLoopRun + 767
39 CoreFoundation 0x00000001033d5d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
40 GraphicsServices 0x000000010524cf04 GSEventRunModal + 161
41 UIKit 0x0000000101d37e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
42 Sales Rabbit 0x000000010000c333 main + 115
43 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000103ac35fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

As far as I can tell the crash is happening when we call

```
[curView becomeFirstResponder];
```

curView is not nil, and is a uitextfield
Any ideas on what to check or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The exception points to an issue with a nil shadow for a UILabel.  Have a look at your code and see if you are manipulating the shadow property of any labels.

Comment: @Paullw11, yeah, sorry i have looked at the code carefully.  We never touch the shadows of our text fields or labels, or any shadows really.   Thats why i think it may have something to do with an ios 7.1 bug if you or anyone has seen anything similar to this.  All that happens is that when the user hits next, we get the next view by its  tag and set it as the firstResponder.  this worked fine pre ios7, and works well in ios7.1, unless you do this several times, then type something and press it again.  then we get this crash.

Comment: It could well be a 7.1 bug then.  I haven't seen anything like this, but maybe someone else has.  It may also be worth opening a case with Apple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up finding the answer, for some reason someone had written this line of code even though it doesnt seem necessary.

```
[[UILabel appearance] setShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

And this was causing it to crash, but only in the situation that I described above, not when it was set in the app delegate.  It seems like it should be allowed to set a the shadow color to clear, although why you would do this is not apparent to me.

Comment: indeed you were, but so weird that a setting in the app delegate would make a view crash that only contained text fields, and only under such a weird condition.  so i do think it was something with ios 7.1

Comment: Yep.  Programming!  Sometimes I think I should take up something simple like bomb disposal

Comment: THANK YOU! I was getting this crash and it was bugging me!